# File not found in Android Studio using simple-cloud-storage

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

I have some problems with [simple-cloud-storage](https://github.com/pliablematter/simple-cloud-storage).

**The error I get:**

I am able to run Maven and build the `.jar` file but when using it in my Android Studio project I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: var/key/xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.p12: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

**What I have done:**

In `cloudstorage.properties` I have defined:

```
private.key.path=var/key/xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx.p12
```

Before building the `.jar` I placed the key in `simple-cloud-storage/src/main/resources/var/key/` and `simple-cloud-storage/var/key`.

Here's the project directory in Android Studio:

[image: view of project dir in Android Studio]

**My questions:**

- Where in my Android Studio project directory should I place the file?
- Do I need to specify the location of the file in Android Studio?